# password probability

Tags: probability, permutations

I want to calculate the probability of someone guessing the password on the first try. The password must be 8-20 characters, containing at least one capital letter and one number.

I attempted the problem and my answer doesn't make sense to me.

First I calculated the total number of possible characters (26 upper case + 26 lowercase + 10 digits)

Then I put 1 as the numerator.          1/62

I then used permutations. Due to the fact that there are 8-20 possibilities of characters I did 62P and the numbers ascending from 8 to 20.

62P8 + 62P9 + 62P10 + 62P11 + 62P12 + 62P13 + 62P14 + 62P15 + 62P16 + 62P17 + 62P18 + 62P19 + 62P20 = 2.29314618x10^34

I then used that number as the denominator and put 1 as the numerator.

1/2.29314618x10^34 = 4.360820992x10^-35

I wanted my answer to be a percentage, as the question asks for a probability.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why did you use permutations?  Are passwords not allowed to use the same letter twice?  Probabilities are frequently specified as a real number between $0$ and $1$: is there a specific wording in the question that makes you want a percentage?  (And if so, are you asking how to convert it to a percentage?)

Answer (score 2):

You want words of 8 to 20 characters containing at least one capital and at least one numeral.

Permutations are not the way to go, but the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion is.

There are $\sum\limits_{n=8}^{20} 62^n$ ways to form words of 8 to 20 characters, when each character is selected from $(26+26+10)$ options, with repetitions allowed.   Simplify using the Geometric Series closed form.

There are --*how many?*-- ways to form such words which contain no numerals.

There are --*how many?*-- ways to form such words which contain no capitals.

There are --*how many?*-- ways to form such words which contain neither capitals nor numerals.

Now put it together using PIE, and then simplify.